# How to get only the last values for every unique name in a struct array in Swift4?

Tags: swift, struct

It has the following struct.

```
    struct LastValue {
        var name: String
        var price: Int
    }

    var lastValue = [
        LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 100),
        LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 200),
        LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 150),
        LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 200),
        LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 500),
        LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 700),
        LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 600),
        LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 800)    
    ]
```

I want only the last values ​​of each name.
In other words, In other words, I want to bring only the last values ​​of coffee and desert.

lastValue is dynamic and another value can be added.

The result I want is:

```
LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 200),
LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 800)
```

Comment: Your code blocks are mismatched. There is coffee and dessert in the first block, apples and oranges in the second.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Fixed the code. thanks

Comment: Is your array static or dynamic?

Comment: My array is dynamic and I can continue to add the Name column.

Comment: Is your **name** proprerty static? Names will be **dessert** and **coffee** only or new names may come?

Comment: Other names can be added. I'm sorry I can not explain clearly.

Comment: Please check @RakeshaShastri's answer. It may solve your problem.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I checked it now. Your answer was a great help. thank you very much!!

Comment: @dinggu you should mark @vadian’s answer accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct LastValue {
    let name: String
    let price: Int
}

var array = [
    LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 100),
    LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 200),
    LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 150),
    LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 200),
    LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 500),
    LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 700),
    LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 600),
    LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 800)
]
```

---

### Solution 1

```
let lastValues = array.reduce([]) { (result, value) -> [LastValue] in
    var updatedResult = result
    updatedResult.removeAll(where: {$0.name == value.name})
    updatedResult.append(value)
    return updatedResult
}

for value in lastValues {
    print(value.name, value.price)
}
```

### Solution 2

[@Evgeniy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2092507/evgeniy)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513227/7734643) also seems nice although it can improved like this.

```
let names: Set<String> = Set(array.map( {$0.name} ))

var lastValues: [LastValue] = []
for name in names {
    lastValues.append(lastValue.last(where: {$0.name == name})!)
}

for lastValue in lastValues {
    print(lastValue.name, lastValue.price)
}
print(lastValues)
```

I think this takes atleast 1 + n passes at the array. (One to find the unique names in the array and n passes to find the last for n names. I do not know how `last(where:` works but i'm guessing it goes through the array every time?)

---

**Edit:** Improved the first approach after [@Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11)'s comments.

Comment: If you please elaborate what this reduce function is doing.

Comment: @iPeter it reduces the current array to the result that you want it to be.

Comment: Why do you suggest using a class rather than a struct?  If anything you should change the `var name` and `var price` to `let`s

Comment: @Paulw11 If i use a struct, it tells me `.first` is a get-only property while reducing which is because struct is a value type?

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to mutate the object.  Don't do that.

Comment: @Paulw11 is it worth keeping it as struct if it means i have to remove the current element and replace it with the new one when i could just be updating the `value` of the current one?

Comment: [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53514507/7734643)'s solution is far more elegant than this one. @dinguu you should mark it accepted.

Answer (score 5):

```
let lastCoffee = lastValue.last(where: { $0.name == "coffee" })
let lastDesert = lastValue.last(where: { $0.name == "dessert" })
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively with `Dictionary(grouping:by:`

```
let lastValue = [
    LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 100),
    LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 200),
    LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 150),
    LastValue(name: "coffee", price: 200),
    LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 500),
    LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 700),
    LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 600),
    LastValue(name: "dessert", price: 800)
]

let result = Dictionary(grouping: lastValue, by: {$0.name}).compactMap{$0.1.last}

// [{name "coffee", price 200}, {name "dessert", price 800}]
```

Comment: Nice answer! :)